# Receber dados de um formulário de cadastro feito em modal/bootstrap no php

Tags: php, modal

Tenho o seguinte arquivo index.html no qual possui 2 formulários: de login e o segundo feito em modal para o cadastro. Porém no modal cadastro, os dados digitados pelo usuário não são recebidos no arquivo 'cadastro.php'

Segue o código:

```
      <!-- modal form cadastro -->
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <h3 class="modal-title" style: font-size = "14px">Cadastre-se</h3>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  </div>

                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <h5>Preencha os campos abaixo:</h5>

                      <form method="post" action="php/cadastro.php">
                        <div class ="form-group">
                          <label id "nome_id">Nome:</label>
                          <input type="nome" class="form-control" name ="nome"required style="min-width:310px;">
                          <!--------------------------------------------->
                            <label id ="email_id">E-mail:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"required style="min-width:310px;">
                              <!--------------------------------------------->
                            <label id ="senha_id">Senha:</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha"required style="min-width:310px;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" value ="btn-cadastra">Continuar</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

---

O arquivo 'cadastra.php':

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['btn-cadastra'])) {
  $nome = $_POST['nome'];
  var_dump($nome);

  $email = $_POST['email'];
  var_dump($email);

  $senha = $_POST['senha'];
  var_dump($senha);
}
?>
```

Comment: aparece algum erro? Já tentou colocar na pagina `cadastra.php` apenas um `var_dump($_POST)` no inicio de tudo?

Comment: Consegui! tirei o data-dismiss e funcionou!